# A computation of the rank of the Jacobian of a hyperelliptic curve over a number field using MAGMA

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, magma

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01564),
the authors says that, in order to show the rank of a Jacobian over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 0, they use the L function.

In the section 3.3, the authors compute the rank of the Jacobian of $X_1(n)$ for $n = 13, 16, 18$ over the splitting field $K$ of $x^3 + x^2 - 4x + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

But in order to compute the rank of $J_1(18)(K)$, MAGMA requires the generalized Riemann hypothesis.
And I can't find the code computing the L-function of the Jacobian of a (non-elliptic) hyperelliptic curve over a number field strictly larger than $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there such a function on MAGMA?
Or can we compute the rank in another way?

(If the base field is of exponent $=2$, then we can compute the rank of $J(K)$ using the Mordell Weil groups over $\mathbb{Q}$ of twists of $J$.)

Comment: Your field $K$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. So you can use the twists of the $L$-function of the newforms in question by the Dirichlet characters of conductor 13 and order 3. If none of them vanish, you can conclude that the rank is $0$, due to Kato's result. Otherwise, you may want to compute some $p$-adic $L$-functions to find an upper bound to the rank.

Comment: There is a function in Magma to compute $L$-series of hyperelliptic curves over number fields: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1582#18161 (with a restriction on the reduction at the prime 2). But as Chris Wuthrich indicated, it is much better to compute the L-functions of the twists of the newforms.

Comment: Magma does not actually require you to use GRH; it just warns that without it, the computation may take a while. In fact, it is not that bad: the Minkowski bound for the relevant degree 18 number field is less than 60 million; the computation of the 2-Selmer group takes less than three hours and shows that the group is trivial, implying that the rank of $J(K)$ is zero.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thank you very much! I didn't know the twists of L functions, but I'll study it!

Comment: @MichaelStoll I use MAGMA free online calculator, so its computations are restricted to 120 sec... But thank you for pointing out! Because of a lack of my English skills, I couldn't understand the warning text correctly.